# Retrofit2 Android Studio Emulator - End of input in json array response

Tags: android, json, api, android-emulator, retrofit2

I consume an API from a Laravel backend in the Android Studio Emulator with Retrofit2.

Some times I get an error and others no, but the response is always the same, in the browser and in postman I check that the result from the server is correct.

The error is something like:
`Throw: End of input at line 1 column 2942 path $[104]`

And in the response log I can view that the last bracket of the json array is missing.

```json
[
   {"IdSec":1,"DescSec":"1"},
   {"IdSec":2,"DescSec":"2"},
   {"IdSec":3,"DescSec":"3"}
```

And then the end of the response.

`2020-12-22 09:13:30.184 5720-5832/uy.gub.poderjudicial.samprimero I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (2941-byte body)`

This seems to be happening only in the emulator, on the phone the result is always correct.
I welcome any suggestion that it may be, as it is difficult to test this way.

Comment: Please uninstall exist app from emulator and reinstall. May be its work.

Comment: I tried but without success, the problem persists.